# Why does the SQLite3 ASP.NET Connecters for Membership provider does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net, apache, mono, mod-mono

I am new to ASP.NET, I am using `mod_mono` in Apache with Debian.
I am using ASP.NET Web Forms.
I am trying to implement ASP.NET Membership in my web application.
First, I followed the instructions in the documentation for using SQLite (https://www.mono-project.com/docs/faq/aspnet/#providerexception-from-sqlitemembershipprovider)

Then, I got an error almost identical to the error in the FAQ.

I changed the data source in the connection string to a file and it still did not work.

I created the exact file with the exact schema listed in the documentation.
I made the permissions of the file world-writable and readable, and it still did not work.

After, all of that it did not work.

I have researched everywhere.

Please help

Comment: Deciding to change from SQLite database and then use MySQL is certainly possible (which database are you using,). Did you install the MySQL or SqLite provider? Correct MySQL (or Sqlite) drivers need to be installed. Somewhat doubtful that such drivers are written 100% in managed (.net) code and thus such drivers will not work . Such drivers are written for windows, and as such, they are not 100% pure .net code, and thus attempting to use such providers with mono is a long shot.

Comment: Trying to use mono and replace IIS (windows web server) is difficult and not recommended with webforms unless you are using .net core in place of .net framework. So, .net core will happy run on Linux, but attempts to use .net framework + mono + replacing IIS web server is VERY challenging here, and such setups don't work all that well. So, in most cases, using webforms does require windows + IIS (windows web server). I suggest running this on windows, or convert or use a .net core application which as I noted is happy to run on a non windows server.

Comment: I am editing legacy code

Comment: Well, the fact of having to work with legacy code MAKES A STRONGER case that such code will have windows dependences and thus will require you to have IIS as the web server.  As I stated, those ODBC drivers are not 100% .net code, and they often have some windows dependencies in such drivers. So, yes, the fact that you working with legacy code IS ALL THE MORE reason to run IIS web server on windows.  I mean, anything more then 1 day of time, and you lost any cost savings here. So, I suggest running such legacy code systems on windows, and you REALLY but REALLY need to use IIS web server here.